# difference between each.with_index and each_with_index in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm really confused about the difference between `each.with_index` and `each_with_index`. They have different types but seem to be identical in practice.

Answer (score 218):

The [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) method  takes an optional parameter to offset the starting index. [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_index) does the same thing, but has no optional starting index.

For example:

```
[:foo, :bar, :baz].each.with_index(2) do |value, index|
    puts "#{index}: #{value}"
end

[:foo, :bar, :baz].each_with_index do |value, index|
    puts "#{index}: #{value}"
end
```

Outputs:

```
2: foo
3: bar
4: baz

0: foo
1: bar
2: baz
```

Answer (score 57):

`each_with_index` was introduced into Ruby earlier. `with_index` was introduced later:

1. to allow  wider usage with various enumerators.
2. to allow index to start from a number other than `0`.

Today, using `with_index` would be better from the point of view of generality and readability, but from the point of view of speeding up the code, `each_with_index` runs slightly faster than `each.with_index`.

When you feel that a single method can be easily expressed by straightforward chaining of a few methods, it is usually the case that the single method is faster than the chain. As for another example of this, `reverse_each` runs faster than `reverse.each`. These methods have reason to exist.