# How to loop rails images in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I need to loop images stored in my database. For the upload I use paperclip. Here you can see my variable passed from controller to the view.

```
@slides

 => [#<Content id: 1, title: "Slider1", content: "", modal_name: "slider", created_at: "2016-09-07 13:01:38", updated_at: "2016-09-07 13:01:38", content_type_id: "2", image_file_name: "family.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 862276, image_updated_at: "2016-09-07 13:01:37">, #<Content id: 2, title: "Slider2", content: "", modal_name: "slider", created_at: "2016-09-07 13:02:17", updated_at: "2016-09-07 13:02:17", content_type_id: "2", image_file_name: "go.png", image_content_type: "image/png", image_file_size: 449856, image_updated_at: "2016-09-07 13:02:17">, #<Content id: 18, title: "family", content: "", modal_name: "family", created_at: "2016-10-04 12:53:15", updated_at: "2016-10-04 12:53:15", content_type_id: "2", image_file_name: "family.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 862276, image_updated_at: "2016-10-04 12:53:15">, #<Content id: 19, title: "go", content: "", modal_name: "go", created_at: "2016-10-04 12:53:32", updated_at: "2016-10-04 12:53:32", content_type_id: "2", image_file_name: "go.png", image_content_type: "image/png", image_file_size: 449856, image_updated_at: "2016-10-04 12:53:32">, #<Content id: 20, title: "family2", content: "", modal_name: "family2", created_at: "2016-10-04 12:53:53", updated_at: "2016-10-04 12:53:53", content_type_id: "2", image_file_name: "family.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 862276, image_updated_at: "2016-10-04 12:53:52">]
```

It's a hardcoded view and looks perfect but I need to create a loop which breaks everything. This is my view :

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <%= image_tag('user/go.png', class: 'fill img-responsive') %>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Caption 1</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <%= image_tag('user/family.jpg', class: 'fill img-responsive') %>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Caption 2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <%= image_tag('user/family.jpg', class: 'fill img-responsive') %>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Caption 3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</header>
```

Comment: Are u trying to loop `div.item` with `image_tag`? And can u add code with ur attempts ?

Comment: Yes, It breaks the slider

Comment: Are you saying that the code above is working properly?

Comment: Yes, I just want to list the data from @slides

Comment: Why don't you just loop through them and display them?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.. Because u have to also loop **`INDICATORS`**..

```html
<!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <% @slides.each_with_index do |slide, i| %>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to=#{i) class="#{'active' if i == 0}"></li>
    <% end %>
  </ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @slides.each_with_index do |slide, i| %>
      <div class="item #{'active' if i == 0}">
        <%= image_tag('user/' + slide.image_file_name , class: 'fill img-responsive') %>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Caption 1</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Here is a great example how `each_with_index` works and what are differences between `each` > [STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258086/difference-between-each-with-index-and-each-with-index-in-ruby)

Comment: Ok, Now I have all images but the slider does not making loop

Comment: Doesnt making the loop at all or showing the images?