# Merge items of two arrays into new array

Tags: ruby

I am browsing through the ruby [Array iterators](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose). And I can't find what I am looking for and I think it already exists:

I have two arrays:

```
["a", "b", "c"]

[0,1,2]
```

And I want to merge as so:

```
[ [0, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "c"] ]
```

I think the iterator exists in the standard library (I used it before) but I am having trouble finding its name.

Comment: Use `arr1.zip(arr2)`. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-zip

Comment: `[arr1, arr2].transpose` will work too.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
[0,1,2].zip(["a", "b", "c"])        # => [[0, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "c"]]
```

From the official documentation of the `Array#zip` function:

> Converts any arguments to arrays, then merges elements of self with  corresponding elements from each argument.
>
> This generates a sequence of ary.size n-element arrays, where n is one more than the count of arguments.

For more info and some other examples, refer to:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-zip

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the zip function

https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index
See this post [difference between each.with_index and each_with_index in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258086/difference-between-each-with-index-and-each-with-index-in-ruby)

or if you have specific values and you want to map them you would use map or zip. It explains it well in this post 
[Combine two Arrays into Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174913/combine-two-arrays-into-hash)